# FFMPEG works in command line but not in exec(), it returns 127

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

The command is

```
ffmpeg -i path/to/video.avi path/to/video.mpg
```

and it works fine from the command line. However, when I call it with PHPs `exec()`, the return value is 127, it doesn't seem to detect FFMPEG. What am I doing wrong?  I'm in localhost and the safe mode is off, but I'm new to both FFMPEG and `exec()`, so it may be a noob mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: exec is enabled? safe_mode? Did you check apache log?

Comment: What if you `exec()` /usr/bin/ffmpeg?

Comment: Use the full path to ffmpeg - whatever account is running PHP apparently doesn't have it on the path.

Comment: path problem? permissions problem?

Comment: It was a path problem, thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
exec(/path/to/ffmpeg -i path/to/video.avi path/to/video.mpg);
```

Comment: That was it! The path was `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` (I've got Mac OSX Lion). Many thanks.

Comment: No problem. Usually when you get a 127 code while using exec() it means PHP can't find the program you are trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

did you register your ffmpeg command as a PATH Environment variable in Linux / Windows ???? it seems that you did not set it as a PATH variable that's why you have to include full path to FFMPEG command so that it worked for you.