# ffmpeg is not running from php exec() function, work from command line

Tags: php, ffmpeg

When i run the ffmpeg command it is working from command line. but when i try from php `exec()`. it returns 127 error.

my ffmpeg

```
root@w1 [/]# which ffmpeg
/root/bin/ffmpeg
```

this is my code

```
ffmpeg-y -i /home/castbox/public_html/IGVideo/upload/tamil/videos/testing/test_ig.mp4 -acodec libfdk_aac -ab 24k -ar 44100 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 31 -b:v 200k -g 72 -f hls -hls_time 3 -hls_list_size 999 -s 426x240 /home/castbox/public_html/IGVideo/upload/tamil/videos/testing/test_ig-240-index.m3u8

when i run this code in from command line it work fine. but when try to run from php exec i am getting failed, it returns 127.
```

i had tried like this also

```
/path/to/ffmpeg-y -i /home/castbox/public_html/IGVideo/upload/tamil/videos/testing/test_ig.mp4 -acodec libfdk_aac -ab 24k -ar 44100 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -level 31 -b:v 200k -g 72 -f hls -hls_time 3 -hls_list_size 999 -s 426x240 /home/castbox/public_html/IGVideo/upload/tamil/videos/testing/test_ig-240-index.m3u8
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Could that be permissions related ?

Comment: your binary is in `/root/` dir. webserver runs at different user and most likely dont have access to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14403013/ffmpeg-works-in-command-line-but-not-in-exec-it-returns-127
( don't know how to add duplicate questions the nice way )

Answer (score 0):

use `system()` instead of `exec()`

try below code :

```
use system("ffmpeg -i input.wmv -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -preset slow -crf 22 -movflags +faststart output.mp4")
```

Comment: fine,but that's more useful if explain more or maybe put a part of code in your answer .

Comment: use system("ffmpeg -i input.wmv -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -preset slow -crf 22 -movflags +faststart output.mp4")